# Compiling function with predefined expression

Tags: compile

I'm using the Compile function in Mathematica to compute say the following :

```
f=Compile[{x,_Real},Cos[x]]
```

Then I can compute f[x] for x taking any real value. Ok, let's say now that I have an expression like
`tmp=Cos[x]`.

My question is the following: Is there a way that I can compile the expression assigned to `tmp` without explicitly typing "Cos[x]" in the `Compile` function ? I.e. I want to do something like :

```
f=Compile[{x,_Real},tmp]
```

But that won't work it seems. In principle I'd like the value assigned to tmp to be a somewhat huge and complicated symbolic function of `x` that I would like to compile for numerical efficiency.

Comment: `f = With[{tmp = Cos[x]}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, tmp]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
compiler[fun_] := Compile[{{x, _Real}}, fun]

compiler[Sin[x] + x^2 - 1/(1 + x)]
```

[image]

```
cf = compiler[Cos[x]];

cf /@ Range[-3., 3., 6/12.]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is the fact the the dummy variable `x` doesn't appear explicitly in `tmp` before it `tmp` is evaluated. To fix this, you could define `tmp` as a function instead. So, I think defining your function as follows should work:

```
tmp[x_] = Cos[x];
f = Compile[ {x_Real} , tmp[x] ];
```

Moreover, I don't think the definition of the `tmp` function has to be a delayed expression.

Comment: Kris, your reasoning is flawed. Please see `CompilePrint[f]` (after loading the package ``<<CompiledFunctionTools` ``) to understand that your approach doesn't work. The reason is the `HoldAll` attribute of `Compile`.