# How to use Compile

Tags: compile

Consider the code below:

```
variable = Sin[x];
fun = Compile[{x}, variable ];
fun[1]
```

When I do this I get the error:

```
 CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression Sin[x] should be a machine-size real number 
 CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

However, if I use:

```
 fun = Compile[{x}, Sin[x]];
```

Everything is fine. I need to compile as I presented first, the one which gives error because in my case `variable` is a huge very big expression. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/compiling-function-with-predefined-expression/51295#51295

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a slight syntax error and a deeper problem binding the x in your "variable" to the x you have in the Compile function.  Both can be fixed...

```
variable = Sin[x];
fun = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate[variable]];
fun[1]
```

You must tell Compile that x is Real, hence the _Real (it only has zero dimensions so this is assumed).

The x in Compile[{{x etc) is local to Compile, its not the same x you have in Sin[x] so Evaluate forces variable to be evaluated before Compile looks at it.

Comment: I have 63 variables. How can I generate `{x,_Real}` automatically for them? Suppose they are `Subscript[a,i,j]`.

Comment: I'm not sure that Complile will work with subscripted symbols (almost certain it wont infact).  I'd convert these to a3b4 or something before even trying.

Comment: I don't know about a3b4. What is a3b4?

Comment: I would setup a set of replacement rules Subscript[a,i,j]->aibj where aibj are actual symbols (a1b1, a1b2 etc).  Use those rules on your expression variable and in the Compile function.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [`CompilationOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationOptions.html?q=CompilationOptions)

```
fun = Compile[{x}, variable, CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

This will automatically inline the definition of `variable`, which is unknown to the compiler otherwise.

Comment: Can I use some unknown parameters in the `variable`?

Comment: @yashar I don't completely understand what you mean with "unknown parameter". Is `x` in your example "unknown"? If you have multiple parameters, e.g. `variable2 = Sin[x + a]; fun2 = Compile[{x, a}, variable2, 
CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]; then `fun2[1, 2]` works, but `fun2[1, b]` will fall back to the uncompiled function.

Comment: I want to use this compiled function in NMinimize. Can NMinimize use a compiled function?

Comment: @yashar Yes, with `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`. See [`RuntimeOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html).